# iOS OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView and iFrame

Tags: cordova, iframe, window.location

So this is a strange dilemma.

I am using zRSSFeed to bring an RSS feed into an iOS app. I set OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to NO and and links to _blank and everything worked fine. I also added a Refresh Navigation button with window.location.reload(); for the RSS page in case the user is offline and nothing is shown.

I added an iFrame on a separate page to display some web content from our site. Also works well. However now when I hit the Refresh button, the iFrame opens up. If I set   OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to YES, the Refresh button works again but the RSS links open in the app and I can't get back to the app.

What the heck?

I'm not sure what code to put in for helping with this.

```
plugins.tabBar.createItem(
"page3",
"some name",
"some.png",{
onSelect: function() {
$.mobile.changePage("#page3", {transition: "slide", reverse: false});
plugins.navigationBar.setTitle("some name");
plugins.navigationBar.setupLeftButton(null,"someother.png", function() {
window.location.reload();
})
plugins.navigationBar.hideRightButton();
selectedTabBarItem = "page3";
}
})
```

Comment: This was solved. window.location.reload() was reloading entire document. Because I am using JQueryMobile this loaded all pages. When it got to the iFrame it opened it. We set up a button that simply reloaded the XML info on RSS page.